# Сборка при помощи xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как сделать сборку, требующуюся в *itunes connect*?

То ли там какой то двоичный файл нужен, то ли что-то другое.

Если двоичный файл, то как его сделать и впоследствии загрузить, если что-то другое, то что? И как загрузить?

Comment: есть какая то ошибка на посмотреть?

Comment: Нет, суть в том, что я вообще не понимаю как что и куда загружать

Comment: туториал какой то по этому вопросу смотрели?

Comment: Естественно, в туториалах по этому вопросу всегда есть плюсик напротив слова буилд, а у меня такого и в помине нет.

Comment: Что бы вы понимали о чем я, буилд это типо окошечко в которое надо каким то образом сборку кинуть перед отправкой на проверку.

Comment: покажите скриншот (отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте)

Comment: кажется понял. имеется ввиду плюс в itunesconnect?

Comment: Да itunesconnect

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В xcode выбрать устройство, и в меню Product выбрать Archive (если будет выбран симулятор кнопка будет неактивна).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого в меню Window выбрать Organizer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее сделать validate и потом Upload to appstore

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- В itunesconnect номер версии должен быть тот же, что и у билда в xcode
- если при валидации выскочат ошибки создайте отдельный вопрос с описанием ошибок.
- после загрузки надо подождать примерно пол часа - час, чтобы билд появился в списке в itunesconnect
- если до конца для билд не появится в списке увеличить номер build на один и загрузить заново - есть такая проблема в itunes когда билды зависают на обработке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вы меня выручили.